# StatelessWidget to StatefulWidget

Tags: flutter, statefulwidget, statelesswidget

I'm adapting a class from Wikipedia Explorer (open source) to browse pre-selected pages. I'm trying to add a page counter that it doesn't update because it is a StatelessWidget. Can someone help me to turn it into StatefulWidget?

```
class NavigationControls extends StatelessWidget {
  const NavigationControls(this._webViewControllerFuture)
      : assert(_webViewControllerFuture != null);

  final Future<WebViewController> _webViewControllerFuture;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<WebViewController>(
      future: _webViewControllerFuture,
      builder:
          (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<WebViewController> snapshot) {
        final bool webViewReady =
            snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done;
        final WebViewController controller = snapshot.data;
        return _buttonsPagination(webViewReady, controller, context);
      },
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can automatically convert it by pressing a shortcut on your keyboard above `StatelessWidget` and it *should* provide you the option to convert to a `StatefulWidget`.

On Mac try: <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>

On Window try: <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>

Anyway, here you have it:

```
class NavigationControls extends StatefulWidget {
  const NavigationControls(this._webViewControllerFuture)
      : assert(_webViewControllerFuture != null);

  final Future<WebViewController> _webViewControllerFuture;

  @override
  _NavigationControlsState createState() => _NavigationControlsState();


class _NavigationControlsState extends State<NavigationControls> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<WebViewController>(
      future: widget._webViewControllerFuture,
      builder:
          (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<WebViewController> snapshot) {
        final bool webViewReady =
            snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done;
        final WebViewController controller = snapshot.data;
        return _buttonsPagination(webViewReady, controller, context);
      },
    );
  }}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just place your cursor on the `StatelessWidget`, press `Alt + Enter` and click on Convert to `StatefulWidget`. All the boilerplate code will be created for you, automatically.

Yay!

[image]