# How to convert a Stateful widget into a Stateless widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a stateful widget and I want to convert it into a stateless widget. I know how to convert a Stateless widget into a Stateful widget. Just like a Stateless widget is there any shortcut available to convert a Stateful widget.

I am using an Android Studio. 
Thanks :)

Comment: There are no shortcuts for it

Comment: This answer solves it https://stackoverflow.com/a/59931359/6736510

Answer (score 50, accepted):

One Simple Trick

```
    class Counter extends StatelessWidget {
//   @override
//   _CounterState createState() => _CounterState();
// }

// class _CounterState extends State<Counter> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      
    );
  }
}
```

Just comment in between and change the statefulwidget to statelesswidget

Comment: Don't forget to add `const Login({super.key});` like so:

>
>    class Login extends StatelessWidget {
>      const Login({super.key});
>    
>    //   const Login({super.key});
>    
>    //   @override
>    //   State<Login> createState() => _LoginState();
>    // }
>    
>    // class _LoginState extends State<Login> {
>      @override
>      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
>

Comment: I tried to format that last comment so many different ways but, apparently, you can't do that.

Answer (score 3):

No there is no keyboard shortcut until now

Answer (score 3):

You can use @Nirmal 's Trick for converting to stateless and for Renaming variables(gotta convert from widget.variable to just variable) you can just Find `widget.` and replace with empty value
like this and hit replace all

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is no shortcut on Android studio. Best option change 'StatefulWidget' to 'StatelessWidget' and delete the associated boiler plate code.

```
class TaskTile extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TaskTileState createState() => _TaskTileState();
}
```

Change to:

```
 class TaskTile extends StatelessWidget {

    }
```

Comment: Wrong. There is a shortcut in Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Simple three steps on android studio to convert stateful widget to stateless widget

1. comment state class of the stateful widget and delete the commented area.
2. change the stateful widget name that the class extends to statelessWidget
3. press control R, and it will open two text fields for replace function above your code, press **widget.** into the upper text field, and **leave the lower one empty**, then **click on replace all button**.
   This process will help you convert all the final variables that were convert by the stateful Widget back to what they were before.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple shortcut in Android Studio.

**Step 1:** We initially have a StatefulWidget.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CategoriesScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;

  const CategoriesScreen({super.key, required this.title});

  @override
  State<CategoriesScreen> createState() => _CategoriesScreenState();
}

class _CategoriesScreenState extends State<CategoriesScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('Hello World'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

**Step # 2:** Place your mouse anywhere in the Widget's class name line of code

[image]

**Step # 3:** Press on your keyboard the keys: Option + Enter.

[image]

**Step # 4:** Select the option "*Convert to StatelessWidget*".

**Step # 5:** Now we have a StatelessWidget.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Hover your cursor to StatelessWidget and use option + return, IDE will show you to convert this class to a Stateful Widget. Tap that option and following code is generated for you.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/3084

Comment: his question is asking for the opposite!